# BackgroundWorker works first time, but fails the second time

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

Im having an odd issue with my implementation of a BackgroundWorker class. It is inside my program that will run some tests (for some hardware which is not important for this question). 
Here is my code for the BackgroundWorker:

```
public AllTests(MainMenu p)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        this.parent = p;

        generateCaseLabels(tc.getTCs());

        var testThread = new BackgroundWorker();

        // Tell the testthread what to do
        testThread.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
        {
            List<BaseTestCase> cases = tc.getTCs();

            foreach ( BaseTestCase test in cases )
            {
                test.execute();
                while (!test.Done) { Thread.Sleep(500); }

                if (test.Passed)
                {
                    passed.Add(test);
                }
                else
                {
                    failed.Add(test);
                }
            }
        };

        // Start the TestReport after the testing is completed
        testThread.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
        {
            TestReport newWindow = new TestReport(parent, passed, failed);
            testThread.CancelAsync(); // reset the testThread (?)
            log.append(this, "--- DONE TESTING --------------------");
            newWindow.Show();
            this.Close();
        };

        // Start the testthread
        testThread.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        testThread.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
```

The odd thing that happens with this code is when started for the first time it works great, but when again navigation to this `AllTests` window the `TestReport` window is instantly opened, indicating that the `testThread.RunworkerCompleted` is immediately called. So my question: Does anyone know a smart thing to do with resetting the BackgroundWorker or something, or have an answer for this weird behavior?

BTW here's how i call the AllTests Window:

```
 private void startTests(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        log.append(this, "--- STARTING ALL TESTS --------------------");
        AllTests newWindow = new AllTests(parent);
        newWindow.Show(); this.Close(); 
    }
```

Thanks for your help!
Robbert.

PS If i made any spelling errors or the question is not clear enough; please excuse me- english is not my native language and this is my first post on StackOverflow! Thanks!

Comment: What does `tc.getTCs()` return? new set of un-executed test cases everytime? My doubt is it behaves differently when called second time. Could you use a breakpoint and check?

Comment: The `tc.getTC()s` method points to a `CaseManager` class, which is a Singleton. The goal of this window is to test all the cases that the `CaseManager` can offer. So this function only asks the `CaseManager` for the programs available testcases. It always finds the same testcases so that seems to work fine.

Comment: I think it's because you put the codes of BackgroundWorker in the constructer method, move them into another method and try again.

Comment: just tried your suggestion, did not help. I put every method call from the constructor into a seperate method and then called that method from the `startTests` method shown above. Same result

Comment: Do not call CancelAsync. More general, Completed should check for errors (args.Error).

Comment: Ok, so I found the bug. Turns out YK1 in the comments was in the right direction. My `CaseManager` class kept the TestCases in the 'Done' state. First time around the new objects were completely empty and the second time the Done parameter was already filled to true.

I added a resetMethod in my `CaseManager` and that fixed it.
Anyway, thanks for your input.

Also, I cant seem to put this as an answer for my question because my rating is too low :I.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how your "AllTests" windows is being closed.  For example, in this simplified test, it works and calls the background worker every time:

```
// simple main form with a button to open the 2nd form
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow() { InitializeComponent(); }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { new PopupWindow().Show(); }
}

// 2nd popup window constructor (hence background worker) fires after form is closed and re-opened from the main form
public partial class PopupWindow : Window
{
    public PopupWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;

        var testThread = new BackgroundWorker();
        {
            testThread.DoWork += (sender, args) => { MessageBox.Show("doWork running"); };
            testThread.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) => { MessageBox.Show("doWork completed"); };
            testThread.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            testThread.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
}
```